# Decode a json containing HTML

Tags: html, json, swift, nsjsonserialization, decodable

I have a real response fetched from SO's socket mentioned in the sample **code below**. I need to decode it to some type of object. So I defined two decodable structs: `SocketResponse` and `Question`.
Then I tried to decode it with a default `JSONDecoder`.

But since the `data` key contains massive invalid json formatting, it is not going to work and throwing me this error:

> dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: **"The given data was not valid JSON."**, underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 2.})))

I tried the `JSONSerialization` as well but it couldn't decode it and throwing a similar error.

So how can I **decode this type of string into the the typed object without loosing the HTML formatting?** (Since responses may be different and the only thing we can relay on is the `data` value is always a `String` containing some **HTML** code.)

### - The Playground:

Here is the simple reproducing code you can play with:

```
struct SocketResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let action: String
    let data: T
}

struct Question: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let body: String
    let tags: [String]
    let siteid: Int
    let noAnswers: Bool
    let hasBounty: Bool
    let fetch: Bool
}

let responseData = """
{
"action": "1-questions-newest-tag-ios",
"data": "{"id":"57238686","body":"<div class=\"question-summary\" id=\"question-summary-57238686\">\r\n <div class=\"statscontainer\">\r\n <div class=\"stats\">\r\n <div class=\"vote\">\r\n <div class=\"votes\">\r\n <span class=\"vote-count-post \"><strong>0</strong></span>\r\n <div class=\"viewcount\">votes</div>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"status unanswered\">\r\n <strong>0</strong>answers\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"views \" title=\"1 view\">\r\n 1 view\r\n</div>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"summary\">\r\n <h3><a href=\"/questions/57238686/how-to-realize-a-movable-controller-in-ipados-like-mail-app-in-ipad\" class=\"question-hyperlink\">How to realize a movable controller in iPadOS, like mail APP in iPad</a></h3>\r\n <div class=\"excerpt\">\r\n Mail App in iPad, when we create a new mail, the controller will be presented. But in iPadOS system, this controller can be moved, and if move it to the left side or right side, it can become a ...\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"tags t-ios t-swift t-ipad t-ipados\">\r\n <a href=\"/questions/tagged/ios\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;ios&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">ios</a> <a href=\"/questions/tagged/swift\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;swift&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">swift</a> <a href=\"/questions/tagged/ipad\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;ipad&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">ipad</a> <a href=\"/questions/tagged/ipados\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;ipados&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">ipados</a> \r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"started fr\">\r\n <div class=\"user-info \">\r\n <div class=\"user-action-time\">\r\n <a href=\"/questions/57238686/how-to-realize-a-movable-controller-in-ipados-like-mail-app-in-ipad\" class=\"started-link\">asked <span title=\"2019-07-28 07:08:46Z\" class=\"relativetime\">just now</span></a>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"user-gravatar32\">\r\n <a href=\"/users/11847413/peipei\"><div class=\"gravatar-wrapper-32\"><img src=\"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-RJzULVcP1iM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3reW_khZzpeiqEPv6Cww36Wohd_oUg/photo.jpg?sz=32\" alt=\"\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\"></div></a>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"user-details\">\r\n <a href=\"/users/11847413/peipei\">peipei</a>\r\n <div class=\"-flair\">\r\n <span class=\"reputation-score\" title=\"reputation score \" dir=\"ltr\">1</span><span title=\"1 bronze badge\" aria-hidden=\"true\"><span class=\"badge3\"></span><span class=\"badgecount\">1</span></span><span class=\"v-visible-sr\">1 bronze badge</span>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n</div>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n</div>","tags":["ios","swift","ipad","ipados"],"siteid":1,"noAnswers":true,"hasBounty":false,"fetch":false}"
}

""".data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(SocketResponse<Question>.self, from: responseData)
    print(json)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: `action` & `data` must be surrounded with quotation marks to be valid JSON.

Comment: `data: "{"id":"57238686"` where does the json start and end here?!

Comment: They need quotation but it isn't enough to be a valid json @Dementic

Comment: @Liam at the end of the line `"fetch":false}"`

Comment: You also need to escape `"id":"57238686","body"`

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**

I understand you. Before decode data perform simple adaptation of response:

```swift
struct SocketResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let action: String
    let data: T
}


struct Question: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let body: String
    let tags: [String]
    let siteid: Int
    let noAnswers: Bool
    let hasBounty: Bool
    let fetch: Bool
}

let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SO", withExtension: "txt")
var responseStr = try String(contentsOf: fileURL!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

responseStr = (responseStr as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")
responseStr = (responseStr as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
responseStr = (responseStr as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "\"{\"", with: "{\"")
responseStr = (responseStr as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "}\"}", with: "}}")


let responseData = responseStr.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(SocketResponse<Question>.self, from: responseData)
    print("Success", json)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**P.S.** please note that construction `\"` is transformed to `"`. You need to use `\\"` even in triple brackets.

Comment: I don't think changing `Decodable` to `Codable` is a key here. It's needed only for encoding and looking for `diff`. Thanks you for mentioning that. But I already saw that and as I said, This is from actual StackOverflow's working socket and I don't have any power to change the response data. So I'm looking for a working mapper from this to the correct decodable JSON or anything like that.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini sorry, forgot about removing `\r\n`. Please, check now

Comment: It's working with the responseStr you provided. But same error with the original one that I posted They are slightly different.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini can you please give file example of response? As I mentioned `\"` converts to `"`, end there no way to distinguish.

Comment: Absolutely. [Here is a fresh one](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/a1f2207cac2432044dec641d1fbba2ab). This is the original response.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini added you SO.txt to resources in playground. Works as expected. Read code from resources updated.

Comment: It seem ok +1, let me check in the real situation and I will accept it then. You are vary hard worker. Thanks a lot.

Comment: {
                                             "title_properties": {
                                                 "title": "<p class='cParaH1 cPx24 cPt16b8 '><span style=\"color:#ee2737\">20% off</span><span style=\"color:#002855\"> test</span></p>".
I have json like this but i can't decode. I think the issue is with "". Can any one help